# Facebook Login Button Termination in xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I am using Xcode 9 and i set the compiler to Swift 3.2
I installed Facebook Login with Cocoapods and everything compiles without any error but whenever i run it in the simulator i click on the login button it crashes with only this printed in the console:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

and this is my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
    loginButton.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

And this is my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    return handled
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pviI.png)

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Wsy.png)

Comment: Go to the last tab on the left pane. See the latest build and click on it. You will see the complete log. Post that. Lets see whats the problem

Comment: Post got updated

Comment: Did you try cleaning the build folder once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AppDelegate`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, you have to return the boolean returned from the `sharedIstance.application(....)`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    return bool
}
```

After check your `Info.plist`you should have something like this. `FacebookAppID` and `FacebookDisplayName` are required:

[image]