# Getting Exception When using Facebook login in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, nsexception

I am using Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004) and i set the compiler to Swift 3.2 I installed Facebook Login with Cocoapods and everything compiles without any error but whenever i run it in the simulator i click on the login button it crashes with only this printed in the console:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

this is my ViewController.swift:

**I HAVE REFERED THIS SOLUTION BUT NOT WORKED**
[Facebook Login Button Termination in xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387724/facebook-login-button-termination-in-xcode-9)

This is my app delegate file

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
        return bool
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return handled
    }
```

This is my view controller.swift file

```
import UIKit
import Pods_FacebookSocialLogin
import FBSDKLoginKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {    
    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            print("sucessfully logged in")
        }


    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("logout from faceboook")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)

        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 60, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)

        loginButton.delegate = self

    } 
}
```

Comment: Above the line from debugger should be the reason, paste that too, please.

Comment: That is the only error on console shows after cliicking on facebook button and if I remove OS_ACTIVITY_MODE from EDIT scheme it shows other error which are not relevant